# ffmpeg crossfade between 2 videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I have multiple videos and I want to concatenate them with the crossfade effect between. This is an example with 2 720p videos but the command resize the output at 960x720.

```
command = "ffmpeg -i 7.mp4 -i 8.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black -filter_complex \"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=6:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[va0];[1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+6/TB[va1];[2:v]scale=1280x720,trim=duration=11[over];[over][va0]overlay[over1];[over1][va1]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]\" -map [outv] out.mp4"
system command
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd input should be `-f lavfi -i color=black:s=1280x720:d=11`. Remove `[2:v]scale=1280x720,trim=duration=11[over]`. The first overlay will reference `[2:v]` instead of `[over]`.

Issue here is that the scale filter, by default, aims to preserve the display ratio of its input. Default size of `color` is 320x240 i.e. 4:3, hence 960x720 in the output.